# Nested dictionary to multi-index DataFrame (specific example)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary, nested, multi-index

I've looked at these pages:
[Nested Dictionary to MultiIndex pandas DataFrame (3 level)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30384581/nested-dictionary-to-multiindex-pandas-dataframe-3-level)
[Pandas Dataframe from nested dictionary of pandas dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64659837/pandas-dataframe-from-nested-dictionary-of-pandas-dataframes)
[Dict of dicts of dicts to DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455388/dict-of-dicts-of-dicts-to-dataframe?noredirect=1&lq=1)

What I want to do is very similar to third example except I want to switch the index order (minor before major) and not have the outer index repeated. Here is my initial dictionary:

```
budget = {'January':{'income':{'work1':1982,'work2':1983},'expenses':{'rent':1500,'insurance':110}},
        'February':{'income':{'work1':1982,'work2':1983},'expenses':{'rent':1500,'insurance':110}},
        'March':{'income':{'work1':1982,'work2':1983},'expenses':{'rent':1500,'insurance':110,'other':150}},
        'April':{'income':{'work1':1982,'work2':1983},'expenses':{'rent':1500,'insurance':110}},
        'May':{'income':{'work1':1982,'work2':1983},'expenses':{'rent':1500,'insurance':110,'groceries':50}}
        }
```

Output from third page:[image]

Desired output Excel example (but want as DataFrame):[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: [DataFrame.swaplevel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) -> `df = df.swaplevel()`?

Comment: @HenryEcker Wow that was simple. I've never seen that swaplevel() function. Thank you so much! Unless I start to overcomplicate things, this should work!